# Little help boxes for sign up form

Tags: html, css, django

I created a signup page for my website with Django.

In this form, I want to put little boxes or ballons next to input fields.

For example, when user click or hover the box next to password input field, it should be written that "The password should be 8 letter and includes 1 uppercase" etc.

How can I do it?

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/signup.css' %}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" id="toggle--signup" name="toggle" class="ghost" />

 <! ––  <img class="logo framed" src="https://www.tumblr.com/images/logo/logo_large.png?v=7ea0eb57dd627a95f82be5bde0c43d59" alt="Tumblr logo" /> ––>


  <form class="form form--signup framed" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <h1 class=" text--centered">PHARSYS</h1>
      <h2 class="text text--centered text--omega">Join Us!</h2>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus required id="id_username" class="input input--top">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="first_name" maxlength="30" id="id_first_name" class="input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="last_name" maxlength="30" id="id_last_name" class="input">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="input" name="email" maxlength="254" id="id_email"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input" name="password1" required id="id_password1">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" class="input" name="password2" required id="id_password2">

        <select class="input" name="user_type" required id="id_user_type">
            <option value="" selected>User Type</option>
            <option value="pharmacist">Pharmacist</option>
            <option value="manager">Medical Repository Manager</option>
        </select>
      <button type="submit" class="input input--submit">Sign Up!</button>

    <a class="text text--small text--centered" href="/users/login">I am already a member</a>

  </form>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found a solution to this [here](http://psacake.com/web/jl.asp), but I'll show you how it'd be used in your code:

**CSS:**

```
a.info{
position:relative; /*this is the key*/
z-index:24; background-color:#ccc;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none}

a.info:hover{z-index:25; background-color:#ff0}

a.info span{display: none}

a.info:hover span{ /*the span will display just on :hover state*/
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:2em; left:2em; width:15em;
    border:1px solid #0cf;
    background-color:#cff; color:#000;
    text-align: center}
```

This'll control what the box actually looks like when you hover over something it's being used on, so feel free to change it as you see fit, obviously. Putting it in your signup.html would look a bit like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a class=info href="#"><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus required id="id_username" class="input input--top">
<span>I'm a tooltip!</span></a>
```